# Exception on System.Drawing.GDIPlus when built for Mac App Store

Tags: mono

I posted this on the mono forums with no luck:

The following code is causing me some headaches:

```
private void MyMethod(string Filename) 
{
     Bitmap bmp = null; 

     try 
     { 
         // load the qr stuff 
         bmp = new Bitmap(Filename); 

         // etc...
```

When I run it in the debugger/ide I have no issues, however when I build the app and create an installer for the Mac App store I get the following exception:

An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus

This seems like some sort of configuration issue, or maybe a dll isn't being put in the build. Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Apologies if this has already been answered and I haven't found it.

JT

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/DllNotFoundException

Comment: Cody Gray: I appreciate the link, will this resolve the issue on target machines when they download the app from the store or will this only resolve it on my machine?

Comment: The full exception with stack trace (for both exceptions, you're showing the exception for another, previous exception) would help a bit to diagnose. In any case this exception is usually related to X11 (sorry I can't be more specific since I haven't actually run into this myself).